# Can we instantiate an object from generic type at runtime?

Tags: java, object, generics, runtime

Can we instantiate an object from generic type at runtime?
I've a class:

```
MyClass<T> implements SomeInterface<T> {
..
public T someMethod() {
return <object of Type T> // Desired!!!
}
..
}
```

Or let suppose I'm calling this method from some other class where I need an instance of generic type:

```
TestMayClass {
DesiredClass t = new MyClass<DesiredClass>().someMethod();
// Can I have generics type at run time and construct object from it then return to calling method? Manipulating generic type??
}
```

: This code's not compiled, it's just imaginary code to have something is similar way.

Comment: Generics in Java are erased at runtime. The only way to achieve something like that is to pass a proper `Class` object and use `newInstance` or one of its constructors if you know which arguments they need.

Comment: Yeah correct! erasure are there but a Class object still maintains some information about generics. Its not completely erased. thanks

Answer (score 2):

No you can't do that in Java. Even if we put [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) aside, how could the compiler know that the invoked constructor exists?

The closest thing in Java that could suit your requirement is [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).

Comment: Its just a case, I can play around reflection to instantiate an object if I have class anyhow at run-time with me. So Think this problem is as I want to have a class of Type given at the time of declaration/initialization. Yeah erasure are there but a Class object maintains some information about generics, I'm not sure if it have the exact type we are declaring an reference/object. So wtill I've same doubt about to have type? Thanks